TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Logged out
I have a bot and at some point it shuts down with the error TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Logged out. After ~20 minutes it starts up again and after ~10 minutes again TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Logged out what does this mean?
I revoke a new token, but the problem was not solved

I import from aiogram.client.telegram import TelegramAPIServerfrom aiogram.client.session.aiohttp import AiohttpSession
and I add session to my bot object like bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN, base_url=LOCAL_API_URL,session=session, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)) 
LOCAL_API_URL is http://localhost:8081/bot
I run this, It work.
Note: Your local server have to run. You will know about it more

A litte hint is how to run local server ./telegram-bot-api --api-id=<your_telegram_api_number>--api-hash=<your_telegram_api_hashcode> --local
